# Custom paging in Company Directory Sharepoint 2013

Tags: people-search, paging

I've create a Company Directory just like the picture has shown below. And I want to make some small change to paging of the default list of SP 2013 as description in picture. Is there any way to do this?[image]

I just find out, todo this I must to modify some code in Control_SearchResults.html . But I dont know how to do this, anyone can help me? :) And here is a link that I find : http://melcher.it/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-search-navigate-first-page/

[image]